# Split into multi rows based on target table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table where i want to join and show quantity with details. table are join with ITM,DIA , and total Qty is equal in both table on ITM/DIA combination

I want to split table2 quantity on table1 and populate table2 data along with table1 data.

I have below data for your reference, "table1" and "table2". and you can see my **expected result in table "tableResult"**

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`ITM` varchar(5), `DIA` varchar(4), `LOC` varchar(4), `ID` varchar(3), `QTY` int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`ITM`, `DIA`, `LOC`, `ID`, `QTY`)
VALUES
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'LOC1', 'ID1', 3),
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'LOC2', 'ID2', 4),
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'LOC2', 'ID2', 6),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC2', 'ID2', 6),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC3', 'ID3', 18),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC4', 'ID4', 90),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC4', 'ID5', 23),
    ('Item1', 'DIA3', 'LOC5', 'ID6', 50),
    ('Item1', 'DIA3', 'LOC6', 'ID7', 20),
    ('Item2', 'DIA1', 'LOC4', 'ID8', 44),
    ('Item2', 'DIA2', 'LOC5', 'ID8', 21),
    ('Item2', 'DIA3', 'LOC6', 'ID9', 20)
;


CREATE TABLE table2
    (`ITM` varchar(5), `DIA` varchar(4), `NTA` varchar(5), `QTY` int)
;

INSERT INTO table2
    (`ITM`, `DIA`, `NTA`, `QTY`)
VALUES
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'NTA1', 10),
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'NTA2', 3),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'NTA3', 30),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'NTA4', 7),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'NTA5', 100),
    ('Item1', 'DIA3', 'NTA6', 70),
    ('Item2', 'DIA1', 'NTA7', 22),
    ('Item2', 'DIA1', 'NTA8', 20),
    ('Item2', 'DIA2', 'NTA9', 6),
    ('Item2', 'DIA2', 'NTA10', 15),
    ('Item2', 'DIA3', 'NTA11', 8),
    ('Item2', 'DIA3', 'NTA11', 12)
;


CREATE TABLE tableResult
    (`ITM` varchar(5), `DIA` varchar(4), `LOC` varchar(4), `ID` varchar(3), `QTY` int, `NTA` varchar(5), `NewQTY` int)
;

INSERT INTO tableResult
    (`ITM`, `DIA`, `LOC`, `ID`, `QTY`, `NTA`, `NewQTY`)
VALUES
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'LOC1', 'ID1', 3, 'NTA1', 3),
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'LOC2', 'ID2', 4, 'NTA1', 4),
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'LOC2', 'ID2', 6, 'NTA1', 3),
    ('Item1', 'DIA1', 'LOC2', 'ID2', 6, 'NTA2', 3),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC2', 'ID2', 6, 'NTA3', 6),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC3', 'ID3', 18, 'NTA3', 18),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC4', 'ID4', 90, 'NTA3', 6),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC4', 'ID4', 90, 'NTA4', 7),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC4', 'ID4', 90, 'NTA5', 77),
    ('Item1', 'DIA2', 'LOC4', 'ID5', 23, 'NTA5', 23),
    ('Item1', 'DIA3', 'LOC5', 'ID6', 50, 'NTA6', 50),
    ('Item1', 'DIA3', 'LOC6', 'ID7', 20, 'NTA6', 20),
    ('Item2', 'DIA1', 'LOC4', 'ID8', 44, 'NTA7', 22),
    ('Item2', 'DIA1', 'LOC4', 'ID8', 44, 'NTA8', 20),
    ('Item2', 'DIA2', 'LOC5', 'ID8', 21, 'NTA9', 6),
    ('Item2', 'DIA2', 'LOC5', 'ID8', 21, 'NTA10', 15),
    ('Item2', 'DIA3', 'LOC6', 'ID9', 20, 'NTA11', 8),
    ('Item2', 'DIA3', 'LOC6', 'ID9', 20, 'NTA11', 12)
;
```

Could you please share your solution on this? appreciate lot on your valuable ideas..

Comment: Is this really an Oracle database? If so, what is the version? The syntax you have used for your insert statements is not valid Oracle syntax, which is why I ask.

Comment: This can never ve Oracle as the syntax is only supported by MySQL.